# Java / Android auto-resolving generic type. Asking for step-by-step guidance to understand

Tags: java, android, generics

I was recently working on some Android code (this should be a generic Java question - pardon the pun - about generics and Java auto resolving the type).

Here is my code (Android-based, but please create a java specific version if you need to)

```
class ViewFinder<T extends View> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final static <T> T byId(View view, int resource) {

        return (T) view.findViewById(resource);


    }

}
```

Here is the interesting bit...

```
// Convert XML UI component definitions into the static View Holder object

// Here is what we normally have to do for Android to convert the XML into a UI component
holder.txtGroupName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtGroupName);

// This is what I can do with my ViewFinder class above!        
holder.txtGroupName = ViewFinder.byId(row, R.id.txtGroupName);

// This is what I was EXPECTING to do with my ViewFinder class above!       
holder.txtGroupName = ViewFinder<TextView>.byId(row, R.id.txtGroupName);
```

No I know that Java (not Android) is resolving the Generic T type to be a TextView UI component, **but why and **how****?

Can I get a "play-by-play" of what is going on here? I want to be able to figure out if this is going to happen  before I code something next time.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Yes, I am using Java 7. But I am still kind of confused by it. Given the `ViewFinder`'s `byId(...)` method. How does this work? I went through it with the debugger, but there was not enough to see the detail very finely. I know it is `Type Inference` but I am wondering how it works on a very fine level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are running Java 7, take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

To scratch the surface of what is going on: Part of the task of the Java compiler is

- Parsing - rough syntactic check and builds an Abstract Syntax Tree AST.
- Weeding - further checks on the AST.
- TypeValidation - and I think this is where the magic happens, at this point the AST is validated and marks are added on every node for variables, expressions etc. The TypeValidation process adds Types to the nodes and ensures that these are correct. With the Java 7 infering of types, I assume that this phase is extended to automatically add Types on the right hand side of assignments, if of course valid. When moving on the the next phase things such as 
  `List<String> str = new ArrayList<>()`, is translated to `List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>()`.
- ...
- In the end Java Bytcode is outputted, which as bonusinfo always starts with 0xCAFEBABE.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Your answer is complete and correct. I was looking to follow it with my finger, but I don't think that would work in this case. fyi, I completely understand the `diamond` usage at the end of point 3. I don't really understand my usage, but knows it works.

Comment: Glad to help. And did get that you understand diamond, it was just to explicitly show an example of the Type being automatically set in place of the diamond by the compiler. I did not cover the why part, which I guess is just syntax sugar. I dont think I will use this feature that much because 1) have tried moving from java 7 to 6, a lot of refactor 2) late assigment of fields in the middle of a lot of other code, here it is not clear what Type that assignment has, when revisiting the code after 2 weeks as you only see the diamond. Then one has to scroll all the way back up to the field.

Comment: And just to clarify, in your usage the compiler idd automatically translates ViewFinder.byId into ViewFinder<TextView>.byId as the type is infered from the left hand side of the assignment.